# Google APAC(CodeJam) Tiling Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, proof-of-correctness

I am stuck at the following question [Problem Statement](https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/3214486/dashboard#s=p3).
I have thought about this for some time and then looked at some clues for the problem because I could not come up with a solution. My understanding is that this is a special case of "Bin Packing" problems which in general are NP-Hard. 
Looking at this idea in particular [CodeForces Blog Idea](http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/13781), I am unable to understand why this even works optimally here. In particular how can we prove that this algorithm is optimal ?

> Problem Statement :
>
> Enzo is doing renovation for his new house. The most difficult part is
>   to buy exactly the right number of tiles. He wants N tiles of
>   different sizes. Of course they have to be cut from the tiles he
>   bought. All the required tiles are square. The lengths of side of the
>   tiles are 2^S1, 2^S2, ..., 2^SN. He can only buy a lot of tiles sized
>   M*M, and he decides to only cut tiles parallel to their sides for
>   convenience. How many tiles does he need to buy?

Comment: Or another algorithm solving this problem with convincing proof of correctness will also do.

Comment: Not a proof but some handwaving intuition: the reason why greedy algorithms for bin packing are typically not optimal is that two smaller squares can be bigger than one big one. Because all side lengths in this problem are powers of two, this cannot happen.

Comment: I understand that the fact that the bins fit into another is playing a part here but formally I don't have an understanding how that helps.

Comment: I think the proof could work as follows: given an arbitrary solution, can you prove you can align all squares so that every cut is a guillotine cut (i.e. a straight cut from one side of the rectangle all the way to the other)? This should be possible because of the powers of 2. Then all you need to show still is that handling the squares in order of descending size is optimal. This could be proved by showing that if the smaller square doesn't fit after the bigger one, they wouldn't both fit anyway.

Comment: Can you please elaborate as to how powers of 2 play a role in proving the first subpart ?

Comment: I have added the problem statement for convenience.

Comment: `Can you[@VincentvanderWeele in particular] please elaborate as to how powers of 2 play a role in proving [all (required) squares can result from side-to-side cuts]` If all required side lengths are powers of the same base, for any two given sizes, one length is an integer multiple of the other.

Comment: @greybeard  How does that imply that this kind of non-guillotine cut cannot exist ? (http://imgur.com/a/8PtH0)

Comment: `How does that imply that this kind of non-guillotine cut cannot exist ?` Not at all. It _does_ imply that non-guillotine cuts have no advantage over guillotine cuts.

Comment: @greybeard But Vincet said "I think the proof could work as follows: given an arbitrary solution, can you prove you can align all squares so that every cut is a guillotine cut (i.e. a straight cut from one side of the rectangle all the way to the other)" ?

Comment: I suppose the confusion comes from the word "align". What I meant to say is that you can shift and swap some squares so that there is a guillotine cut.

Answer (score 4):

The essence of the proposed solution is *first fit decreasing* (FFD) heuristic.

Let's call sizes of for the Bin Packing problem *nesting* if for each *a<sub>i</sub> < a<sub>j</sub>*, a<sub>i</sub> = k<sub>ij</sub> a<sub>j</sub>. Notice, that according to this definition, the original problem is *Nesting Bin Packing* problem.

Let's proof that FFD heuristic solves *Nesting Bin Packing*. Consider a counter-example: non-increasing sequence of item sizes *a<sub>i</sub>* and an optimal solution OPT that is not achieved by FFD heuristics. There is the first *i* that requires bin number OPT+1. This means, that all previous items was packed and there are no space for item *i*.

Let's compare the distribution of the first *i-1* items using FFD and optimal distribution of *i* items. The total size of placed items in optimal distribution are higher by *a<sub>i</sub>*. So, for at least one bin, the total size of items in optimal distribution is greater than in FFD distribution. Due to *nesting*, all items considered so far, may be split in some number of *a<sub>i</sub>*-sized items, so both totals are multiples of a<sub>i</sub>, and the minimal possible difference between them is *a<sub>i</sub>*. Therefore, we found a bin for item *i*, that leads to contradiction.

The contradiction is clear in the 1D case (original *Bin Packing* problem), but no so clear for 2D case. Let’s introduce a grid with cell size *A=√a<sub>i</sub>* and the origin in the top-left corner. Side length of already placed title will be multiples of *A*. We’ll shift all titles in both solutions to the top (in order from top to bottom), then, to the left (in order from left to right). After that all tiles will have integer coordinates on the grid. But there are more occupied cells in optimal solution than the FFD one, so there are should be at least one *A×A* cell that is occupied in optimal solution, and is free in the FFD one. Let’s use it to place tile *i*.

Comment: I have two doubts: 1) Did you mean "non-increasing sequence of items .. " ? 2) The line "so the minimal possible difference is between total bins sizes are ai" does not seem to be clear.

Comment: 1) Sure. 2) Added clarification.

Comment: Ok I get that we have shown that there exists a combined area of ai in the FFD solution but how are we sure that this area is in one single tile i.e. it could be possible that there is no single tile with area ai but many small areas in several tiles contribute to the difference of ai ?

Comment: None of the items smaller than *a<sub>i</sub>* was placed yet, so they cannot fragment the bin.

Comment: But why is it not possible for larger tiles to fragment it in such a way that no single un-fragmented space is >= ai ?

Comment: Explicit clarification for 2D case added.